# Anychart/Anystock Basic Interface Questions

Tags: javascript, charts, anychart

I'm deciding on whether to choose Anystock to build a financial app and I have a few questions about it for anyone that has experience.

1. To start with, [this link](http://www.anychart.com/products/anystock/gallery/Stock_Technical_Indicators/Bollinger_Bands_Width_(BBands_Width).php) shows technical indicators on the graph, but I always see them being controlled via the Anystock legend within the graph area. I'm wondering if they can be controlled and turned off and on via external events from outsdie js code. I'd like to have my own panel of turning indicators on and off and hide the built in Anystock legend.
2. Also, when dealing with annotations such [as these](https://playground.anychart.com/api/7.13.1/core/annotations/anychart.core.annotations.PlotController.getAnnotationAt-plain), I'm wondering if you're able to change the highlight color of the yellow handles which allow you to reshape and move the annotations.
3. Does anyone have experience with styling the navigator elements on the bottom? Such as the handles used to zoom in and out of the navigator timeline? Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Please, take a look at [technical indicators demo](http://www.anychart.com/solutions/technical-indicators/), it's in the final stage of the development right now. More indicators and minor UI fixes are coming.
   Also, our [technical indicators documentation](https://docs.anychart.com/Stock_Charts/Technical_Indicators/Overview) articles may be useful.
2. You definitely can change any kind of annotation settings, take a look at [Drawing Tools and Annotations Demo](http://www.anychart.com/solutions/drawing-tools/). Also [documentation articles](https://docs.anychart.com/Stock_Charts/Drawing_Tools_and_Annotations/Overview) may be useful.
3. You can simple use CSS, all navigation elements has an CSS classes so you could override any default settings. Here is a list of CSS classes which as I think the most useful in your case.
   `anychart-range-picker
   anychart-range-selector
   anychart-button
   anychart-label-input
   anychart-input-label`

Comment: I greatly appreciate your input and thoroughness in your answer. As I make this decision for the team, it would really help to know a timeline on a release of this new version. Could you give me a rough estimate about whether it'll be within the next week or month?

Comment: I wold say [AnyStock 7.14.0](http://www.anychart.com/products/anystock/roadmap/) will be released between 29-31 of May and technical indicators demo will be released at the same time or with one-day delay max.

Comment: Thank you @Roman. Will you be releasing the ability to use a crosshair on the graph in this version such as [here](http://techanjs.org/)? Or is this a possibility in the current version?